# converting jquery plugin into angular component

Tags: jquery, angular

i have building a website that uses a jquery plugin named **Wow Slider** now i have used it in standard html before, i want to use it in angular!

i have imported jquery and works fine, now i need to copy the plugin resources, i copied them inside **src/assets/*** now when i am including the plugin the index.html from src folder it is working fine, let me share the code,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Doubledoubleangular</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/engine1/style.css"/>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <div id="wowslider-container1">
    <div class="ws_images"><ul>
            <li><img src="assets/data1/images/slide1.png" alt="Bringing People Together" title="Bringing People Together" id="wows1_0"/></li>
            <li><img src="assets/data1/images/slide2.png" alt="bootstrap carousel" title="Every one wants a piece of me" id="wows1_1"/></li>
            <li><img src="assets/data1/images/slide3.png" alt="Every one wants a piece of me" title="Every one wants a piece of me" id="wows1_2"/></li>
        </ul></div>
    <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
            <a href="#" title="Bringing People Together"><span><img src="assets/data1/tooltips/slide1.png" alt="Bringing People Together"/>1</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Every one wants a piece of me"><span><img src="assets/data1/tooltips/slide2.png" alt="Every one wants a piece of me"/>2</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Every one wants a piece of me"><span><img src="assets/data1/tooltips/slide3.png" alt="Every one wants a piece of me"/>3</span></a>
        </div></div>
    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/engine1/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

the problem is it comes to bottom of the page, and moreover it might be included in some pages or not, so i need to make it a component,

now first of all i created a component named **wowslider**
after that i am importing files in the **angular.json** file where we normally add jquery/bootstrap etc,

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/engine1/style.css"
            ],
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/engine1/wowslider.js",
              "src/assets/engine1/script.js"
            ],
```

**wowslider.component.html**

```
<div id="wowslider-container1">
  <div class="ws_images"><ul>
          <li><img src="assets/data1/images/slide1.png" alt="Bringing People Together" title="Bringing People Together" id="wows1_0"/></li>
          <li><img src="assets/data1/images/slide2.png" alt="bootstrap carousel" title="Every one wants a piece of me" id="wows1_1"/></li>
          <li><img src="assets/data1/images/slide3.png" alt="Every one wants a piece of me" title="Every one wants a piece of me" id="wows1_2"/></li>
      </ul></div>
  <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
          <a href="#" title="Bringing People Together"><span><img src="assets/data1/tooltips/slide1.png" alt="Bringing People Together"/>1</span></a>
          <a href="#" title="Every one wants a piece of me"><span><img src="assets/data1/tooltips/slide2.png" alt="Every one wants a piece of me"/>2</span></a>
          <a href="#" title="Every one wants a piece of me"><span><img src="assets/data1/tooltips/slide3.png" alt="Every one wants a piece of me"/>3</span></a>
      </div></div>
  <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<app-wowslider></app-wowslider>
```

but it is not working as it is supposed to, the plugin is breaking, i have debugged it and came to conclusion that the resources from **angular.json** are not loading that is why it is breaking, their is no package available for **wow slider** in **npm** so i had to add it manually,i am using angular 7, any help is appreciated

Comment: try editing this `src/assets/engine1/` to this `../assets/engine1/` in the `angluar.cli.json` file.

Comment: tried! not working